# What is Hudson doing with my Python script?

Tags: python, hudson

I am developing a Python script (here after script) that searches through large log files for a search string. In normal use, it is called from a Hudson front end.

**About the Hudson interface:**
The Hudson job creates a temporary batch file on a connected virtual machine (VM) that calls the script and passes it some parameters. We have had hundreds of successful instances using this setup, but something is now creating an error.

**About the script:**
The log files are contained in dozens of compressed *.tgz* files. My script searches each log in each *.tgz* file.
One of the command line args that my script accepts is a *True/False* parameter called **PROCESS_IN_PARALLEL**. If **PROCESS_IN_PARALLEL** is set to *True*, then each *.tgz* file is searched in its own thread (using the multiprocessing module). If **PROCESS_IN_PARALLEL** is set to *False*, then each *.tgz* file is searched in sequence (using a loop).

**What works:**

1. I have a batch file on the VM that I use for testing my script. I can successfully use this *.bat* to call my script with **PROCESS_IN_PARALLEL** set to either (1a) *True* or (1b) *False*. Of course, it runs much faster when *True* (about 4x faster).
   I have quadruple-checked that this *.bat* passes the same parameters to my script as Hudson, and in the same order. I have also added a line to my script that logs the input parameters to a file, and have found that Hudson is indeed passing the correct parameters in the correct order.
2. I can successfully use Hudson to call my script with **PROCESS_IN_PARALLEL** set to *False*.
3. I have tested the current iteration of my script using the above three test cases multiple times (even using multiple configurations of other parameters), all successfully.

**What doesn't work:**
If I use Hudson to call my script with **PROCESS_IN_PARALLEL** set to *True*, then I get a strange error. Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Scripts\Parse_LogFiles_Archive\parseLogs_Archive_8-19-13.py", line 40, in main  
    searchHits = searchTarList(searchDir, newDirectory, argv)
  File "F:\Scripts\Parse_LogFiles_Archive\parseLogs_Archive_8-19-13.py", line 163, in searchTarList  
    hits = processPool.map(searchTar, tarMap)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 225, in map  
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "E:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 522, in get  
    raise self._value   IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

According to my research, this error happens when Python attempts to read a file which is opened in write mode.

**My question:**
Is there a genius out there who know both Python and Hudson well enough to know what is happening?

Comment: How are you opening the files? If you are using modes `r` or `w`, using `r+` or `w+` may help, if the problem is trying to read files opened in write mode.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida: I am opening the files using tarfile.open(fileName), which provides many features similar to the built-in file.open paradigm. The tarfile module does not require or allow the user to specify r/w when using this function. Thanks for replying!

Comment: `tarfile.open()` does have [many different modes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open), but not with `+`, and the default one doesn't seem worse than any of the others.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida: You are right. I read about the modes weeks ago, and forgot about them because I am doing all reading from these *.tgzs*. I tried switching from the default mode to 'r|*', and the traceback threw `StreamError: seeking backwards is not allowed` (with all other traces being identical to my original error). This is so odd.

Comment: Perhaps running the script via Hudson changes the timing and exposes a race condition? I suspect "Bad file descriptor" would also be a symptom of one thread trying to use a file that another thread has just closed (synchronization issue).

Comment: You can also try setting explicit compression mode (`gz`, I suppose). Maybe the transparent mode needs to open the files first to detect the compression type and that causes a problem.

Comment: @Drew: I commented out 2 lines: one that touches a temp file (mainly for troubleshooting) and another that untars search hits. All my other code that messes with files is necessary for the functionality of my script (I untar log files in memory using thisTarFile.extractfile(logFile) and search the files using if SEARCH_STRING in extractedFile.read()).  
@PauloAlmeida: I tried `'r:gz'` mode.  
Both: I am still getting errno 9. Any thoughts on how I could fix timing issues?